# bank on vs ride on

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What's the difference between the following sentences.

> 1 They’re banking on him to save the match.

> 2 They’re riding on him to save the match.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct as *banking on* means depending on.

The verb *riding on* also means depending on in a certain sense. So it would be fine to say

> There is a lot riding on the result of the match

perhaps because it would decide the outcome of an important trophy or league but it would not work with a person as subject.

Comment: Maybe one way to look at it is that _consequences_ "ride on" something, while stakeholders (people affected by the consequences) "count on" something.